# Python3.2 error; Unable to install or remove anything

Tags: installation, uninstall, python3

I searched around as much as I could, but I couldn't seem to find a solution to fix my problem.

Whether I install anything, remove anything, run `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I still seem to get the following message:

```
Setting up python3.2 (3.2.3-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/py_compile.py", line 187, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/py_compile.py", line 179, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/py_compile.py", line 111, in compile
    with tokenize.open(file) as f:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tokenize.py", line 344, in open
    encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tokenize.py", line 332, in detect_encoding
    encoding = find_cookie(second)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tokenize.py", line 304, in find_cookie
    codec = lookup(encoding)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/encodings/__init__.py", line 98, in search_function
    level=0)
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
dpkg: error processing python3.2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libopenimageio1.0 (1.0.9+git20120918-0irie3~precise1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.2:
 libpython3.2 depends on python3.2 (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package python3.2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libpython3.2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.2
 libpython3.2
```

It's worth mentioning this problem occurred on my desktop right after I was updating and the city's power's just went off. When I booted back on after it returned, the system became immensely slow and updates seemed to show "Partial Upgrade". I canceled it, ran `sudo apt-get install -f` and all the necessary commands to get it running, but it didn't seem to work after that.

Further notes: Upon trying to install Synaptic, I get this error:

```
Setting up python3.2 (3.2.3-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/py_compile.py", line 187, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/py_compile.py", line 179, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/py_compile.py", line 111, in compile
    with tokenize.open(file) as f:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tokenize.py", line 344, in open
    encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tokenize.py", line 332, in detect_encoding
    encoding = find_cookie(second)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tokenize.py", line 304, in find_cookie
    codec = lookup(encoding)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/encodings/__init__.py", line 98, in search_function
    level=0)
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
dpkg: error processing python3.2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.2:
 libpython3.2 depends on python3.2 (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package python3.2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libpython3.2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.2
 libpython3.2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

To reconfigure your dependencies.

You can also try to manually edit your package status file

---

Source: http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution

Comment: I'm not sure if I actually tried that (I did try something "--configure" but in conjuct with a package-name), but that didn't seem to work. For some reason, the conflict with the unconfigured python3 seemed to affect nearly every kind of installation or uninstallation.

Answer (score 1):

I "think" I managed to solve my own problem (though I'm not sure of its consequences). After running "sudo apt-get clean" I hit "sudo nautilus /var/lib/dpkg/info". There, I deleted EVERY file pertaining to the package-names giving me problems (such as every "python3.2", "blender" and "yafaray" file) after backing them up in certain compressed files. After that, I hit apt-get update and apt-get upgrade. Once it showed me no upgrades left, I simply did a "sudo apt-get purge" on both python3 and python3.2, and any residual conflicting packages like yafaray and blender. After that, I reinstalled python3 and python3.2 with the other packages.

Seems to have fixed my problem, but this certainly may not be the best solution. Please feel free to submit your solutions in case others have the same problem as me.